# Rails: flash[:alert] in if-else misbehaving in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails I want to show error message via flash[:alert] if entered date is invalid using JavaScript.
But here it show error even if given date is correct, as first time when page load it show message Invalid date

initially When Page load  then my input text field 'target_month_str' value is '2014/07'

My program  code is:

```
$( "#target_month_str" ).change(function()                        
{                                
  var dt= $(this).val();
  var dtRegex = /^(0|[1-9]\d{3})(\/)(0?[1-9]|1[012])$/;
  var dtArray = dt.match(dtRegex);
  if (dtArray === null){
    "<%= flash[:alert] = 'Invalid date' %>"
  }
 });
```

I don't understand when page load, why this message 'Invalid date' is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Nutshell: Because you set `flash` long before the JavaScript has a chance to execute on the client.

Solution: Continue to use JavaScript/jQuery to display the "Invalid date" message, e.g.,

```
if (dtArray === null) {
    $("div.msgs").text("Invalid date");
}
```

Better yet, use any of the existing jQuery plugins to do this for you.

Comment: Thanx for reply but as I have one partial which handle alert and notice and it will be shown when only any error or notice is there. So i can not use above code. As I have to write two many sentence to format  the message div.

Comment: @Kanti Then tender the partial via Ajax or use a remote form or... etc. Do you understand why your code doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: Render :/ Darn phone.

Comment: As per your suggestion for Ajax request, I can't use it as there are so many error message like this, so i can't create individual partials for the each of them.